# How to remap ("at the software level") the Fn and Ctrl keys in an Acer laptop?

Tags: debian, xorg, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

I have an Acer Aspire V5 laptop for home use whose keyboard's lower-left corner has the keys arranged like this

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Fn</kbd>  <kbd>❖</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd>

This differs from, and IMO is less comfortable than, the arrangements I find in every other keyboard I use, namely these

<kbd>Fn</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>❖</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> (my work laptop)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>❖</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> (my desktops at home and at work)

I really would like the Acer's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and  <kbd>Fn</kbd>  keys to switch places, so to speak.<sup>1</sup>

---

The BIOS for this Acer, AFAICT, offers no option for flipping the  <kbd>Fn</kbd>  and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys.<sup>2</sup>

Is there some way that I can switch these keys by remapping them at the software level?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> The Acer's different layout is more than just an annoyance.  It causes me to make frequent errors (as I press  <kbd>Fn</kbd>  when in fact I want to be pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>).  Moreover, after I become habituated to the Acer, and then switch to my work laptop, I start making the same sort of error all over again.  These errors are often disorienting, especially if I'm working quickly, and they have the potential for being costly.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> My work laptop's BIOS *does* offer such an option, but, ironically, perhaps because I am an Emacs user, I find my work laptop's key arrangement to be the more ergonomically comfortable to the two, by far.  Since I use my work laptop far more than the Acer, I am very reluctant to make it less sound ergonomically by availing myself of its BIOS option.</sup>

Answer (score 5):

<sub>(Converting some deleted comments to an answer)</sub>

The <kbd>Fn</kbd> key is used internally by your keyboard, i.e. it's a hardware modifier and usually `xev` can't see it because it doesn't generate a scancode. So, as far as X is concerned that key doesn't exist. Switch to a VT and then use `showkey -s` and you won't get any output when pressing the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key.